# facebook and google cookie without "allow" page

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I need very small integration with google or facebook,
I only need to identify the person, (and maybe get his email..)

I know I have to make an authorization, but I wonder if there is a small chance that I can come across it and just identify him without the "allow authorization" page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Facebook and Google both require the allow page, even for just getting the email of the user.